# Transparency in ArcMap Graphic Elements

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap

Is it possible to apply transparency to graphic elements in an ArcMap layout?  I'm specifically refering to a neatline -- a box containing my legend, source info, scale bar, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly no, about the best you can do is to either create a feature class to hold "graphic" elements and apply transparency to this, or export your layout as Adobe Illustrator and apply transparencies there.