# Getting transparent graphics in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, convert, transparency-opacity, graphics

I have a point layer symbolized with a logo I created.  I have the layer set to 50% transparency.  I would like to manually rearrange these logos by converting these symbols to graphics.  Once I convert, the transparency is lost.  Is there any way around this?

I am using ArcMap 10.0.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge - a transparency can't be applied to a graphic. You would need a third party software to do it (even then, not sure it would import as transparent, arc tends to white it out). You can maybe export layout view to illustrator, but you won't be able to do it natively.

Comment: +1 for not wasting the OP time trying to get an ArcGIS solution. This [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/transparency-in-arcmap-graphic-elements) gives a kind of workaround (for scale and other layout components) but OP will still need to keep the logos as a feature.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I agree, and that you should do this in Adobe Illustrator. In there you should be able to select all of your points as graphic elements, and apply transparency to them. [Here's some info on how to do this in Illustrator.](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html#about_transparency)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all of your input.  Our client decided to go with a different logo (without transparency) for this project, but this is all good information for future reference.